# Prime Postulate

Tags: prime-numbers

Why is it the case that for every prime number $p_i$ there exist unique positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$
m\,  p_i^2 + 1 = n \, p_{i + 1}
$$
where $m\ne n$ and $m \le p_i$?

That is, why is it that there is some positive integer $m$, less than of equal to the $i$-th prime number $p_i$, such that when  $p_i$ is multiplied by $m$, and one is added,  the result equals the product of the next, $(i + 1)$-st prime number $p_{i + 1}$, and the positive integer $n$, for some $n\ne m$, and for each $i$ there is a unique way of achieving this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. You can typeset mathematical expressions by enclosing them in dollar signs: `$p_i$` gives $p_i$.

Comment: Also, what exactly is your question?

Comment: $p_i=3$ and $p_{i+1}=5$ has two solutions $(1,2)$ and $(6,11)$ for $(m,n)$.

Comment: I don't have a question, but I guess I'm looking for a proof of the statement.

Comment: Yes, but in the second solution, m > p(i), which doesn't follow the stipulation m <= $p(i)$.

Comment: It sounded like you wanted to conclude that, not require it.

Comment: $np_i^2 +1 = mp_{i+1} \iff \gcd (p_i^2, p_{i+1}) = 1$

Comment: $p_{i+1}$ is pretty different from $p_i + 1$.  Is the edit correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right Randall, it should be p_(i + 1)

Comment: Sorry, i've not insered a } in the edit, my fault. I think that now it's correct :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Have to add a few extraneous words here, when thanks would have done, but even so. (Because there's a minimum word limit)

Comment: How do you know that this is true?

Comment: Hunch:  Bezout's identity gives existence of some pair, the required bound on $m$ forces uniqueness.  Just a guess.

Comment: @Randall The key issue is the bound $m\le p_i$.

Comment: I assume this is a homework problem, so I'll just give a hint.  The extended Euclidean algorithm says there are $m,n$ such that $np_i+mp_{i+1}^2 = 1.$  First, you have to show that you can choose $m<0$.  Then you have to look at other pairs $(m,n)$ that satisfy the equation.  General theorem's on the extended Euclidean algorithm (or Bezout's theorem as it's sometimes called) give the results you need.

Answer (score 3):

It's false.

Here's a counterexample . . .

Let $p_i=43$.

Then the smallest positive integer $m$ for which
there exists a positive integer $n$ satisfying
$$mp_i^2 + 1=np_{i+1}$$
is $m=44$, which is greater than $p_i$.

The next two counterexamples are 
$$p_i = 173$$
$$p_i = 18869$$

Those are the only counterexamples with $p_i < 10^6$.

It's conceivable that there are no more counterexamples.

Note that for all $p_i$, the smallest qualifying positive integer $m$ is necessarily less than $p_{i+1}$, so there is a small window of opportunity for a counterexample, namely, $m$ needs to be greater than $p_i$, but less than $p_{i+1}$.

Comment: Okay, that's true. But seeing as it's only one unit bigger than p$i$, the bounding could be changed to reflect this, provided of course, there aren't much more egregious counterexamples (from the point of view of the initial stipulation that m be less than or equal to p$_{i}$, where m >> p$_{i}$.

Comment: @Dolphin For any $i$ there is a unique $m$ with $0<m<p_{i+1}$ such that, for some $n$, we have $m\,p_i^2+1=n\,p_{i+1}$, and it is clear that $m\ne n$. Since $m<p_{i+1}<2p_i$, then no counterexample is too "egregious".

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples. What's interesting though, is that in each case where the initial condition is contradicted, it's always (so far, anyway) equal to a square number greater than p_${i}$. So a broader scope is needed for the original definition.

Comment: @Dolphin: I don't follow: For the examples I gave, what square numbers are you referring to?

Comment: It strikes me as likely that counterexamples will continue to pop up. See my answer for a (wholly non-rigorous) argument.

Comment: @quasi: Simply that the smallest m value was always a square value greater then p_${i}$, i.e. for the case of p_${i}$, it was 174, which is p_${i}$ + 1, and for p_${i}$ = 18869, it was 18878, which again is 9 greater than p_${i}$ in this case. (Admittedly only for the cases you provided, I was just guessing it might hold for all values which are counterexamples. I expect not though, but am curious to see nevertheless).

Comment: In the second case you provided, I meant to say, when p_i = 173, and the m value was 174. Just to make it clear. Also for the first case, 44 is one greater than 43.

Answer (score 1):

The Euclidean algorithm guarantees the existence of a unique $m\lt p_{i+1}$ for which $p_{i+1}\mid mp_i^2+1$. If you believe that each $m\lt p_{i+1}$ has an equal chance of being the unique such $m$ (which is obviously not true, if only because the properties of primes are deterministic, not random), then the probability that $m\le p_i$ is less than $1-{1\over p_{i+1}}$ (since there is at least one $m$ between $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$, namely $p_{i+1}-1$). If you furthermore believe than these probabilities are independent from one prime to another (which isn't true either), then the probability that $m\le p_i$ from $i=N$ to $\infty$ is less than $\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1-{1\over p_{N+k}})=0$.

This is by no means a proof of anything, but it does suggest that the counterexamples found by quasi will continue to pop up. A more careful heuristic examination might even produce a formula for approximately how often.

Remark: Another reason not every $m\lt p_{i+1}$ has an equal chance is that we must have $\left(m\over p_{i+1}\right)=\left(-1\over p_{i+1}\right)$.  But since $m=p_{i+1}-1$ satisfies this constraint, that's not a heuristic-killer.

Comment: Make sense. Assuming independence, can you give a crude upper bound for when the next one is likely to occur, with probability, say $.9$?

Answer (score 0):

Because

$mp_i^2 + 1 = np_{i+1} \iff$

$np_{i+1} - mp_i^2 = 1$

As $\gcd(p_i,p_{i+1}) = 1$

There always are such integers via Euclid's Algorithm.

If $m,n$ are such integers then $m' = m + k*p_{i+1}$ and $n' = n + kp_i^2$ for all $k$ are all such solutions.  (Because $(m+kp_{i+1})p_i^2 +1= mp_i^2 +1+  kp_i^2p_{i+1} = np_{i+1} +  kp_i^2p_{i+1} = (n + kp_i^2)p_{i+1}$.)

And $k$ so that $0 < m + k*p_{i+1} \le p_{i+1}$ is unique by division algorithm.

(You have a typo that $m \le p_i$.  That need not be true.)

(If $n = m$ would imply $mp_i^2 + 1 = mp_{i+1} \implies p_i^2 +\frac 1m = p_{i+1}$ which means $m = 1$ so $p_i^2 + 1 = p_{i+1}$ which means there are no primes between $p_i$ and $p_i^2$ which is impossible.)

Comment: I don't think there is a typo. The question was genuinely about whether the bound $m\le p_i$ holds, even if it turns out that it doesn't in general.

Comment: Yes, it was hard to gauge the background of the question.  The fact that there are counter-examples though pretty much ends it though.